# Can PHP web app. open or list a folder in a client machine

Tags: php

This is my first question on stackflow, my favourite script helper. I have a project that requires interaction with the clients machine to get the contents of a folder, usually scanned images. They are used to search my web app for a match of the image then retrieve the user information. however, I have seen post that said that can only be achieved through Java applet or ActiveX. how can I achieve this considering am developing with PHP/MYSQL.

please anybody with suggestion or guide should help pls...

Comment: Simply, you cannot do this with PHP, it is server side. They would need to upload the images to your app. I don't think javascript has access to the file system either, in which case an applet is the only way to go it seems.

Comment: File system actions are the most heavily locked down operations in browsers, as it would be entirely too easy for malicious sites to steal files from a client's machine. What you want is not possible with plain html/JS.

Answer (score 1):

Can you clarify? Do you want the user to be prompted with a 'browse for file' pop-up or do you want the file to be open/read automatically? Here is some code you can use if you want to have a 'browse for file' window popping up:

```
$ok = validFile($_FILES['uploaded']);
    $uploaded_type = $_FILES['uploaded']['type'];
    $uploaded_size = $_FILES['uploaded']['size'];

    if($ok==0)
        echo 'Sorry. Your file was not uploaded.';
    else
    {
        //inserting file data into DB
        $qry = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table_name (mime, size, created)
            VALUES ('$uploaded_type', '$uploaded_size', NOW())");

        if(!$qry)
        {
           die('Error: ' . mysql_error() . '<br />');
           $ok = 0;
        }

        //updated uniqueID for file
        $filename = explode(".", basename($_FILES['uploaded']['name']));
        $idq = mysql_insert_id();
        $mapName = $filename[0] . $idq . '.' . $filename[1];
        $target = "upload/"; 
        $target = $target . $mapName;

        $qry = mysql_query("UPDATE $table_name SET uniquename='$mapName', path='$target' WHERE id='$idq'");

        if (!$qry)
            die("FAIL: " . mysql_error());

        //uploading file
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target) && $ok == 1) 
        {
            echo "The file ". $filename[0] . "." . $filename[1] . " has been uploaded";
        } 
        else 
            echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
 Please choose a file: <input name="uploaded" type="file" /><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Comment: thank you!Insomnihack for this code....
I have been pondering the best way to implement this, the thing is the image will not be upload to the website, it will read the image as it is scanning in the scanner and then use the it to autheticate the member, i will work like a finger-print authetication system where while the person finger is on the machine or device, the data collected will be used to check for the availability of the person and then autheticate him.